# Replacing top-level (i.e. not enclosed in braces) occurrences of a token

Tags: expl3, token-lists

I'm trying to replace all top-level occurrences of a token by another in a token list. For example, replacing `0` by `1` in `0{0{0}}0` should yield `1{0{0}}1`. I have something that kind of works, but forgets some braces along the way: it returns `10{0}1`. What is the simplest (reasonably efficient) way of doing this?

I can see inelegant and slow ways of doing this (and some slightly inaccurate ones, e.g. testing whether `\tmvip_output_tl` contains more than one token with `\tl_if_single_token:VTF \tmvip_output_tl` instead of testing whether it was enclosed in braces), but there ought to be an elegant and reasonably efficient way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{stix}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_if_single_token:nTF {VTF}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_put_right:Nn {Nf}


\tl_new:N \tmvip_output_tl
\cs_new:Npn \tl_map_variable_in_place:NNn #1 #2 #3 {
  \tl_set:Nn \tmvip_output_tl {}
  \tl_map_variable:NNn #1 #2 {
    #3
    \tl_put_right:NV \tmvip_output_tl #2 % TODO: Make this add braces if needed
  }
  \tl_set_eq:NN #1 \tmvip_output_tl
}

\tl_new:N \ratl_item_tl
\tl_new:N \ratl_old_tl
\tl_new:N \raft_new_tl
\cs_new:Npn \tl_replace_all_top_level:Nnn #1 #2 #3 {
  \tl_set:Nn \ratl_old_tl {#2}
  \tl_set:Nn \ratl_new_tl {#3}
  \tl_map_variable_in_place:NNn #1 \ratl_item_tl {
    \tl_if_eq:NNTF \ratl_item_tl \ratl_old_tl {
      \tl_gset_eq:NN \ratl_item_tl \ratl_new_tl
    } {}
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \input_tl
\tl_set:Nn \input_tl {0{0{0}}0}

\tl_new:N \output_tl
\tl_set_eq:NN \output_tl \input_tl
\tl_replace_all_top_level:Nnn \output_tl {0} {1}

\tl_new:N \expected_output_tl
\tl_set:Nn \expected_output_tl {1{0{0}}1}

\newcommand{\inputtl}{\tl_to_str:N \input_tl}
\newcommand{\outputtl}{\tl_to_str:N \output_tl}
\newcommand{\expectedoutputtl}{\tl_to_str:N \expected_output_tl}

\ExplSyntaxOff

I want to replace all occurrences of 0 that are at the top-level (i.e. not in a group) by 1. It works, but loses the braces in the process: "\inputtl" becomes "\outputtl" instead of "\expectedoutputtl"

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might not be aware because seems it is not said in interface3.pdf, but `\tl_replace_all:Nnn` only replaces what you call "toplevel-occurrences".
So, if using expl3, then - in my humble opinion - the simplest (reasonably efficient) way of doing this is using `\tl_replace_all:Nnn`.   :-)

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_set:Nn \output_tl {0{0{0}}0}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \output_tl {0} {1}
\tl_show:N \output_tl

\tl_set:Nn \output_tl {~0~{~0~{~0~}~}~~0~}
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \output_tl {0} {1}
\tl_show:N \output_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Output on terminal:

```
> \output_tl=1{0{0}}1.
<recently read> }
                 
l.8 \tl_show:N \output_tl
                         
? 
> \output_tl= 1 { 0 { 0 } } 1 .
<recently read> }
                 
l.12 \tl_show:N \output_tl
```

---

The problem with your approach is:

Internally `\tl_map_variable:NNn` is used.

Interface3.pdf says:

> `\tl_map_variable:NNn ⟨tl var⟩ ⟨variable⟩ {⟨code⟩}`
>
> Stores each ⟨item⟩ of the ⟨tl var⟩ in turn in the (token list) ⟨variable⟩ and applies the ⟨code⟩. The ⟨code⟩ will usually make use of the ⟨variable⟩, but this is not enforced. The assignments to the ⟨variable⟩ are local. Its value after the loop is the last ⟨item⟩ in the ⟨tl var⟩, or its original value if the ⟨tl var⟩ is blank. See also `\tl_map_inline:Nn`.

When mapping an item of ⟨tl var⟩ to ⟨variable⟩ `\tl_map_variable:NNn` strips off one level of curly braces that surround that entire item in case such braces are present but does not provide info on whether brace-stripping took place.
Thus ⟨code⟩ cannot be used for forking depending on the presence of such braces. Besides this with `\tl_map_variable:NNn` space tokens between items of the ⟨tl var⟩ are discarded.

---

In case you need it for other purposes/in other contexts, the following `\MyModule_CheckWhetherExplicitBrace:nnn` can be used for testing whether the very first token of a macro argument is an explicit character token of category 1 (begin group).
Usually `{` is the only character where the category code 1 (begin group) is assigned.
The test yields the true branch in case the argument has a first token which is `{1`.
The test yields the true branch also in case the argument has a first token which is , e.g.,  `K1`.
(You can get `K1` by having things tokenized  while `` \catcode`\K=1\relax `` or the corresponding expl3-directive `\char_set_catcode_group_begin:N \K` is in effect.)
After `\let\bgroup={` the control word token `\bgroup` is not an explicit but an implicit character token of category 1(begin group). Thus the test even in this case yields the false branch in case the argument has a first token which is `\bgroup`.

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn

%% Some framework for displaying the test result on terminal:

\msg_new:nnnn {MyModule}
              {Argument does indeed have a first token which is an explicit character token of category 1}
              {The\ argument\ "#1"\ does\ have\ a\ first\ token\ which\ is\ an\ explicit\ character-token\ of\ category\ 1\ (begin\ group).}
              {This\ message\ is\ just\ an\ information.}
\msg_new:nnnn {MyModule}
              {Argument does not have a first token which is an explicit character token of category 1}
              {The\ argument\ "#1"\ does\ NOT\ have\ a\ first\ token\ which\ is\ an\ explicit\ character-token\ of\ category\ 1\ (begin\ group).}
              {This\ message\ is\ just\ an\ information.}

\cs_new:Nn \MyModule_DisplayBraceCheckResult:n {
 \msg_term:nnn {MyModule}
               {Argument does \MyModule_CheckWhetherExplicitBrace:nnn{#1}{indeed}{not} have a first token which is an explicit character token of category 1}
               {#1}
}

%% The test:

%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's first token is an explicit character token of
%% category 1 (begin group)
%%.............................................................................
%% \MyModule_CheckWhetherExplicitBrace:nnn{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                                        {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                                          which is to be checked has a leading
%%                                          explicit catcode-1-character-token>}%
%%                                        {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                                          which is to be checked does not have a
%%                                          leading explicit catcode-1-character-token>}%
\cs_new:Npn \MyModule_CheckWhetherExplicitBrace:nnn #1 {
  \exp:w\exp_after:wN\use_ii:nn\exp_after:wN{\exp_after:wN{\token_to_str:N #1.}
  \exp_after:wN\use_i:nn\exp_after:wN{\exp_after:wN\use_ii:nn \token_to_str:N}
  \exp_after:wN\exp_end:\use_i:nn}{\exp_after:wN\exp_end:\use_ii:nn}
}

\MyModule_DisplayBraceCheckResult:n {ABC}

\MyModule_DisplayBraceCheckResult:n {}

\MyModule_DisplayBraceCheckResult:n {~}

\MyModule_DisplayBraceCheckResult:n {~{A}BC}

\MyModule_DisplayBraceCheckResult:n {{A}BC}

\MyModule_DisplayBraceCheckResult:n {{ABC}}

\MyModule_DisplayBraceCheckResult:n {{}ABC}

\MyModule_DisplayBraceCheckResult:n {{{A}B}C}

\stop
```

Output on terminal and in .log-file:

```
The argument "ABC" does NOT have a first token which is an explicit
character-token of category 1 (begin group).
The argument "" does NOT have a first token which is an explicit
character-token of category 1 (begin group).
The argument " " does NOT have a first token which is an explicit
character-token of category 1 (begin group).
The argument " {A}BC" does NOT have a first token which is an explicit
character-token of category 1 (begin group).
The argument "{A}BC" does have a first token which is an explicit
character-token of category 1 (begin group).
The argument "{ABC}" does have a first token which is an explicit
character-token of category 1 (begin group).
The argument "{}ABC" does have a first token which is an explicit
character-token of category 1 (begin group).
The argument "{{A}B}C" does have a first token which is an explicit
character-token of category 1 (begin group).
```

In case you wish to detect whether an argument—let's denote that argument via `#1`—forms a set of tokens which is entirely nested between curly braces, you can apply `\MyModule_CheckWhetherExplicitBrace:nnn {#1}{...}{...}` for checking whether `#1` does have a first token which is an explicit character token of category 1(begin group) and if so check whether "gobbling"/removing an undelimited argument from `#1` yields emptiness, probably via some variant of `\tl_if_empty:nTF` :

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn

%% Some framework for displaying the test result on terminal:

\msg_new:nnnn {MyModule}
              {Argument does indeed consist of a set of token which is nested in curly braces}
              {The\ argument\ "#1"\ consists\ of\ a\ set\ of\ tokens\ which\ is\ nested\ in\ curly\ braces.}
              {This\ message\ is\ just\ an\ information.}
\msg_new:nnnn {MyModule}
              {Argument does not consist of a set of token which is nested in curly braces}
              {The\ argument\ "#1"\ DOES\ NOT\ consist\ of\ a\ set\ of\ tokens\ which\ is\ nested\ in\ curly\ braces.}
              {This\ message\ is\ just\ an\ information.}

\cs_new:Nn \MyModule_DisplayBraceNestedCheckResult:n {
 \msg_term:nnn {MyModule}
               {
                   Argument does
                   \MyModule_CheckWhetherExplicitBrace:nnn{#1}
                                                          {\tl_if_empty:oTF{\use_none:n #1}{indeed}{not}}
                                                          {not}
                   consist of a set of token which is nested in curly braces
               }
               {#1}
}

%% The test:

%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's first token is an explicit character token of
%% category 1 (begin group)
%%.............................................................................
%% \MyModule_CheckWhetherExplicitBrace:nnn{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                                        {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                                          which is to be checked has a leading
%%                                          explicit catcode-1-character-token>}%
%%                                        {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                                          which is to be checked does not have a
%%                                          leading explicit catcode-1-character-token>}%
\cs_new:Npn \MyModule_CheckWhetherExplicitBrace:nnn #1 {
  \exp:w\exp_after:wN\use_ii:nn\exp_after:wN{\exp_after:wN{\token_to_str:N #1.}
  \exp_after:wN\use_i:nn\exp_after:wN{\exp_after:wN\use_ii:nn \token_to_str:N}
  \exp_after:wN\exp_end:\use_i:nn}{\exp_after:wN\exp_end:\use_ii:nn}
}

\MyModule_DisplayBraceNestedCheckResult:n {ABC}

\MyModule_DisplayBraceNestedCheckResult:n {A}

\MyModule_DisplayBraceNestedCheckResult:n {}

\MyModule_DisplayBraceNestedCheckResult:n {~}

\MyModule_DisplayBraceNestedCheckResult:n {~{A}BC}

\MyModule_DisplayBraceNestedCheckResult:n {{}ABC}

\MyModule_DisplayBraceNestedCheckResult:n {{A}BC}

\MyModule_DisplayBraceNestedCheckResult:n {{ABC}}

\MyModule_DisplayBraceNestedCheckResult:n {{{A}BC}}

\MyModule_DisplayBraceNestedCheckResult:n {{A}}

\stop
```

Output on terminal and in .log-file:

```
The argument "ABC" DOES NOT consist of a set of tokens which is nested in
curly braces.
The argument "A" DOES NOT consist of a set of tokens which is nested in curly
braces.
The argument "" DOES NOT consist of a set of tokens which is nested in curly
braces.
The argument " " DOES NOT consist of a set of tokens which is nested in curly
braces.
The argument " {A}BC" DOES NOT consist of a set of tokens which is nested in
curly braces.
The argument "{}ABC" DOES NOT consist of a set of tokens which is nested in
curly braces.
The argument "{A}BC" DOES NOT consist of a set of tokens which is nested in
curly braces.
The argument "{ABC}" consists of a set of tokens which is nested in curly
braces.
The argument "{{A}BC}" consists of a set of tokens which is nested in curly
braces.
The argument "{A}" consists of a set of tokens which is nested in curly
braces.
```

Comment: For some reason, I assumed that `tl_replace_all` worked on tokens and not items >_< Thank you!

Comment: @xavierm02 `\tl_replace_all:Nnn` works on tokens. But only on toplevel which the documentation doesn't mention. E.g., if the token-list has `\foo\bar` on toplevel, `\foo` would be an item and `\bar` would be another item. But you can use `\tl_replace_all:Nnn` for replacing the token-sequence `\foo\bar`. So it works on tokens, not items. I suppose internally things are done recursively by means of delimited arguments with the stuff to be replaced as argument-delimiter. That would explain both the `{`/`}`/`#`-restrictions and that replacement is on toplevel only.

Answer (score 1):

Very straightforward with a token cycle.  With this definition, anything within a group is echoed directly to the output token list, without substitution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\reptoplist[3]{%
  \tokcycle
    {\ifx#2##1\addcytoks{#3}\else\addcytoks{##1}\fi}
    {\addcytoks{##1}}
    {\addcytoks{##1}}
    {\addcytoks{##1}}
    {#1}%
    \the\cytoks
}
\begin{document}
\reptoplist{0{0{0}}0}{0}{1}

\detokenize\expandafter{\the\cytoks}
\end{document}
```

[image]

p.s. this approach will work even if the input contains spaces and/or control sequences, as in `\reptoplist{0 {0{0}}\today}{0}{1}`.  Of course, with control sequences, the replacement occurs before the control sequence is expanded...however, that too can be changed, if so needed, as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tokcycle}
\newcommand\reptoplist[3]{%
  \expandedtokcycle
    {\ifx#2##1\addcytoks{#3}\else\addcytoks{##1}\fi}
    {\addcytoks{##1}}
    {\addcytoks{##1}}
    {\addcytoks{##1}}
    {#1}%
    \the\cytoks
}
\begin{document}
\reptoplist{0 {0{0}}\today}{2}{3}

\detokenize\expandafter{\the\cytoks}
\end{document}
```

[image]